# Is this passage about different reading speeds an argument?

Tags: logic, argumentation

> The pace of reading, clearly, depends entirely upon the reader. He may
>   read as slowly or as rapidly as he can or wishes to read. If he does
>   not understand something, he may stop and reread it, or go in search
>   of elucidation before continuing. The reader can accelerate his pace
>   when the material is easy or less than interesting, and can slow down
>   when it is difficult or enthralling. If what he reads is moving he can
>   put down the book for a few moments and cope with his emotions without
>   fear of losing anything.  (Marie Winn, The Plug-In Drug)

In my reasoning module, we are presented with this passage (taken from hurley) and to deduce if it is an argument. We discussed and the professor said it is an argument with the conclusion being the first sentence. But when I look at the solutions online answered by other people (chegg), it says it isnt an argument. May I know is it really an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible analysis, based on the first two sentences :

> "The reader may read as slowly or as rapidly as he can or wishes to read. **Therefore**, the pace of reading depends entirely upon the reader."